# replace function isn't working the it supposed to work

Tags: python

Hello guys I'm trying to create a function that returns a list out of a string ((((Without the space))))
I'm using the replace function to remove the space however I'm still getting a space

```py
def str2list(argstr):
    retlist = []
    for c in argstr:
        c=c.replace(" ", "")
        retlist.append(c)
    return retlist

print(str2list('abc efg'))
```

```
output: ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'e', 'f', 'g'] 
desired output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: If `c` is a space `" "`, it gets replaced by the empty string `""` and then you `append` it to `retlist` anyway. The output is as expected. Instead of iterating over individual characters, you can do `list(argstr.replace(" ", ""))`.

Comment: If you do `a = []; a.append('')`, `a` becomes `['']`, not `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing spaces with empty strings, where you would like to remove them from the list entirely. Think about what happens when the loop sees `" "`.

The simple fix is instead to not append spaces.

```
def str2list(argstr):
  retlist = []
  for c in argstr:
    if c != " ":
      retlist.append(c)
  return retlist

print(str2list('abc efg'))
```

Somewhat more elegantly, try

```
def str2list(argstr):
    return [c for c in argstr if c != " "]
```

(Thanks to @Cobra for the improved implementation; I had a clumsy `lambda` at first.)

Answer (score 3):

A simple list comprehension should suffice:

```
def str2list(argstr):
    return [c for c in argstr if c != ' ']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using regex, you may try:

```py
inp = "abc efg"
letters = re.findall(r'[a-z]', inp, flags=re.I)
print(letters)  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

You could also use:

```py
inp = "abc efg"
output = list(inp.replace(" ", ""))
print(output)  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: I'm new to python I'm pretty sure there is a simpler way to do it

Comment: I have given you a simpler version as well, along the lines of what you were trying to do.

Comment: +1 for the `list(inp.replace(" ", ""))`. It's pythonic, beginner-friendly and illustrates an important concept: Strings are sequences of characters, and any sequence can be turned into a list with `list()`.

Answer (score 1):

A very clean solution, without using libraries or replacements, is using [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

The syntax of this tool is as follows:

> [expression for item in iterable if condition == True]

so the code becomes:

```py
def str2list(argstr):
    return [x for x in argstr if x != " "]
```

is the same thing, in a more compact way than the similar function you wrote, with an extra if statement:

```py
def str2list(argstr):
    retlist = []
    for c in argstr:
        if c != " ":
            retlist.append(c)
    return retlist
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to check if a character is a place
`if c == ' '`
or see if it a character is not
`c != ' '`

then you don't need to replace it. You're just changing a `' '` to a `''` then adding it. you need to exclude it

```py
def str2list(argstr):
    retlist = []
    for c in argstr:
        if c != " ":
            retlist.append(c)
    return retlist
```

This will fix your issue.

Or you could just use a comprehension

```
def str2list():
    return [c for c in argstr if c != ' ']
```